# grpc c++ build on macOS Sierra failed because OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier deprecated

Tags: c++, grpc, macos-sierra

I'm building grpc on macOS Sierra following the instruction [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

During the make step, I got an error saying

```
OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier is deprecated:

'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64' is deprecated: first deprecated in OS X 10.12
      - Use
      std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit(std::memory_order_relaxed)
      from <atomic> instead [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    if (OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64(old_value, new_value,
        ^
/usr/include/libkern/OSAtomicDeprecated.h:628:9: note:
      'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
bool    OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64( int64_t __oldValue, int64_t __newValue,
        ^
```

What can I do to install it? Shall I just wait for grpc to fix it in the new OS?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the workaround suggested here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2182
(See the comment from `michael-berlin`)

Comment: bring something here